# Connecting to a Raspberry Pi TightVNC server isn't working with Screenshare on Mac OS X?

Tags: raspbian, networking, headless, vnc, macos

I have a tightvnc server set up on my raspberry pi on port 1 but when I try to connect to it from my mac using the built in screen sharing client i get an error:

```
Connection Failed to:192.168.1.127:1 
Please make sure that Screen Sharing (in the Sharing section of System Preferences)
is enabled on the computer to which you are attempting to connect. 
Also make sure your network connection is working properly.
```

I ran a port scan and I found out that port 1 is not open on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typically a port around 5900 is used for VNC. In your case, you could try 192.168.1.127:5901. The last digit (1 in this case) refers to the virtual display of the VNC server. It usually starts at 0, meaning 5900 is the standard display/port to connect to.

Comment: Great!!! My tightvnc server was setup to use :2 so I had to enter raspberrypi.local:5902 or your_ip:5902 if you don't have Bonjour services installed.